# Can anyone please tell me about linux file handling

Tags: linux

I am using Linux from 6 months I want to learn how this OS actually keep its files. What is the files type and how they be arranged?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Sir I want to know 1. what is the file structure in Linux . Means how the file is kept in memory . Suppose I saved a .txt file how the file will be saved what is the mode of the file ?

Comment: Another part I wanted about the hierarchy of Linux file system which I got already.

Answer (score 2):

Linux File System explained [here](http://www.freeos.com/node/36).

And [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_03_01.html) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) and some architectural point of view from [IBM here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-linux-filesystem/).

If you like presentations you can review [this one](http://www.cse.psu.edu/~anand/spring01/linux/files.ppt).

[Discussion](http://blogs.computerworld.com/15413/the_best_linux_file_system_of_all) about diferences and similarities between linux file system.

> The Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (FHS) defines the directory structure and directory contents in Linux operating systems. For the most part, it is a formalization and extension of the traditional BSD filesystem hierarchy.

Most important directories:

`/bin` - binaries/tools

`/etc` - configuration files

`/usr` - user read only data `/usr/bin` `/usr/sbin` - user tools

`/home` - user's directory

`/root` - admin directory

`/sbin` - executables for deamons and services

`/tmp` - directory where everyone has access

`/proc` - kernel and processes directory for virtual file system

`/boot` - boot loader config

`/var` - directory for files that often change

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: You are absolutely rigth. Let me correct myself.

Comment: I am asking that how file is created and arranged in linux. That means suppose in C when I open a file I use a file structure . So in this operating system what is the structure of a file how that been kept in memory .

Comment: Sir I am asking not about the directory hierarchy of linux but the what are the main attribute of a single file structure . Suppose I store a .txt file how will it be arranged in memory . What is the mode of the file .